# "Портится" класс в теге кнопки WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, классы, button

Пытаюсь передать методу класс, который лежит в теге кнопки, при создании собственно в самом вызове все хорошо.

```
    public void DrowField()
    {
      var button = new Button()
        {
          Tag = new Tag {height=0,width=0 }
        }
    }
    void Panel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tag = (sender as Button).Tag;
        var tag1 = new Tag {height = 0, width = 0 };
        proc.Addmass(tag); //ошибка, хотя все свойства на месте
        proc.Addmass(tag1); //все OK
    }
    public void Addmass(Tag obj)
    { }
    public class Tag
    {public byte height, width;}
```

Сама ошибка: `Ошибка 1 Аргумент "1": преобразование типа из "object" в "tofu.Tag"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип свойства `Button.Tag` - `object`. Это Вы знаете, что там на самом деле тип `Tag`, а компилятору это неизвестно. Ваш код

```
var tag = (sender as Button).Tag;
proc.Addmass(tag);
```

пытается вызвать `proc.Addmass` с параметром, тип которого `object`.

```
Tag tag = (Tag)(sender as Button).Tag;
proc.Addmass(tag);
```

Это тоже сработает:

```
var tag = (Tag)(sender as Button).Tag;
proc.Addmass(tag);
```

---

> что это за уточнение

Это "уточнение" называется *"преобразование типа"* (*"type-cast"*).

Comment: Да, правильно, но что это за уточнение?

Comment: @AlexandrVolkov не люблю деклараций `var` ) - это у меня чисто личное

Comment: Нет, в смысле "(Tag)" и как это называется?

Comment: Соглашусь, из-за этих `var`type'ov у меня было столько проблем.

Comment: Фу ты, фу ты. Что это я? "не известно" написал раздельно. Видимо, устал к концу недели.

Comment: @AlexandrVolkov `var` лучше использовать когда нужен сам объект и не важен его тип. Такое бывает крайне редко и как правило для проверок или передачи объекта, но почему-то все любят использовать это повсеместно. Просто запомните, что использовать `var` без приведения к типу это моветон. У вас в Addmass не неопределённый объект передаётся, а вполне декларированный тип `Tag`.